# How Can I avoid char input for an int variable?

Tags: c++, integer, character, cin

The program below shows a 'int' value being entered and being output at the same time. However, when I entered a character, it goes into an infinite loop displaying the previous 'int' value entered. How can I avoid a character being entered?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int n;

while(n!=0){
            cin>>n;
            cout<<n<<endl;
           }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

**Reason for Infinite loop:**

cin goes into a failed state and that makes it ignore further calls to it, till the error flag and buffer are reset.

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(100, '\n'); //100 --> asks cin to discard 100 characters from the input stream.
```

**Check if input is numeric:**

In your code, even a non-int type gets cast to int anyway. There is no way to check if input is numeric, without taking input into a char array, and calling the `isdigit()` function on each digit.

The function [isdigit()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isdigit/) can be used to tell digits and alphabets apart. This function is present in the `<cctype>` header.

An is_int() function would look like this.

```
for(int i=0; char[i]!='\0';i++){
    if(!isdigit(str[i]))
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: I googled a bit about this, and i found that some "state" of cin is changed to false which makes it skip the cin statement and keep on executing cout

Answer (score 3):

You need to check for cin fail

And

You need clear the input stream

See the following example.
It is tested in recent compilers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void ignoreLine()
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    int num;
    cout << "please enter a integer" << endl;
    cin >> num;

    while (cin.fail()) {
        ignoreLine();
        cout << "please enter a integer" << endl;
        cin >> num;
    }

    cout << "entered num is - " << num << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want use user define function you can use the ascii/ansi value to restrict the char input.

48 -57 is the range of the 0 to 9 values

Comment: it would be great if you can give me an example. Do i have to input 'int' or 'char'?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits> // for INT_MAX limits
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num;
    cout << "Enter a number.\n";
    cin >> num;
    // input validation
    while (cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear(); // clear input buffer to restore cin to a usable state
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n'); // ignore last input
        cout << "You can only enter numbers.\n";
        cout << "Enter a number.\n";
        cin >> num;
    }
}
```