# Input validation in do-while

Tags: c++, validation, vector

I'm having a problem with the input error.My input is validated but my error message "Invalid Range. Please Enter Range 0-100:" is not showing if there's invalid input.

Here's an example:

```
Please Enter Grade 1: 101 (It does not accept input)
Please Enter Grade 1: 321 (It does not accept input)
```

Instead of showing:

```
Please Enter Grade 1: 101 (It does not accept input)

Invalid Rage. Please Enter Range 0-100.
Please Enter Grade 1:
```

Here's My Code:

```
for(vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i < 15; i++)
  {
    do
    {
         cout << "Please Enter Grade "<< i + 1 <<": " << flush;
            cin >> gradesVector[i];
        }
        while(gradesVector[i] < 0.0 || gradesVector[i] > 100.0);
        { 
            cout << "Invalid Rage. Please Enter Range 0-100:\n";
                cout << "Please Enter Grade "<< i + 1 <<": " << flush;
                    cin >> gradesVector[i];
         }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while()` condition should be

`while(gradesVector[i] < 0.0 || gradesVector[i] > 100.0)` and use this code

```
for(vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i < 15; i++)
  {
   int c=0;
    do
    {
        if(c!=0)   //checking that we didnt entered loop for first time
          cout << "Invalid Rage. Please Enter Range 0-100:\n";         

           cout << "Please Enter Grade "<< i + 1 <<": " << flush;
           cin >> gradesVector[i];
           c++;   
     }
        while(gradesVector[i] < 0.0 || gradesVector[i] > 100.0);

}
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it won't output my error message "Invalid Rage. Please Enter Range 0-100: when a invalid input is entered

Comment: wait a min, m updating

Comment: @TayvionPayton check it now

Comment: thanks this helped me out a lot. now i'm having a problem where if i enter a letter it automatically ends the program

Comment: @TayvionPayton see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523569/how-can-i-avoid-char-input-for-an-int-variable

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing a `do` construct with a `while`. Use either not both. Also your test in your `while` does not make sense. It can't be less **and** more at the same time. Edit to the following and it should work

```
for(vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please Enter Grade "<< i + 1 <<": " << flush;
        cin >> gradesVector[i];
        while(gradesVector[i] < 0.0 || gradesVector[i] > 100.0); // or not and
        { 
            cout << "Invalid Rage. Please Enter Range 0-100:\n";
                cout << "Please Enter Grade "<< i + 1 <<": " << flush;
                    cin >> gradesVector[i];
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your while condition is not right.

```
std::vector<double> gradesVector;
gradesVector.reserve(15);
for (std::vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    double grade;
    std::cout << "Please Enter Grade " << i + 1 << ": " << std::flush;
    std::cin >> grade;
    while (grade < 0.0 || grade > 100.0)
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid Range. Please Enter Range 0-100:\n";
        std::cin >> grade;
    }
    gradesVector.push_back(grade);
}
```

Also I would only add the grade to the vector once it is valid.

Comment: This will give infinite loop when invalid input is entered

Comment: @TanujYadav, even before the edit it wasn't giving an infinite loop.

Comment: it will give, because you were adding the input to the vector even if it was invalid, and then you were accessing that value only to check for valid input in further iterations

Comment: Actually my bad, it was indeed the case!

Comment: Thanks alot this was the solution i needed.

Comment: now i'm having a problem whenever i enter a letter it goes into a infinite loop

Comment: This is now a different question, you can find a solution to your problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828937/how-to-make-cin-take-only-numbers)